# Getting the value from a jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI slider that is part of a rating system. You slide to values 1 - 5 in order to rate it 1 thru 5. I have it defaulted to 3 when the slider first appears. The form that it is part of has a hidden input whose value should be the value of the slider, but it is not.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$( "#ratingSlider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 3,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#ratingResult" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#ratingResult" ).val( $( "#ratingSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $("#ratingSlider").change(function(){
        $( "#rateToPost" ).attr('value', $( "#ratingSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
```

I tried making the .val() of #rateToPost to be the .val() of the slider, but it always only gave it 3 (the default value).

How can I make it pass the value properly?

Also, I want to have the value automatically refresh (right now it is displayed using a text box but I really don't want to use a text box) on the page whenever the slider is moved, how can I do that?

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: alos i hink there should be a return somewhere in $( "#ratingResult" ).val( return $( "#ratingSlider" ).slider( "value" ) );

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To display rating as you slide in your slider initialization you need to change the text of that div (Assuming you have a div (not an input box) with an id "ratingResult").
To update the value when user finishes dragging you need to add the change event to the initialization code.

```
$("#ratingSlider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 3,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#ratingResult").text(ui.value);
    },
    //this updates the value of your hidden field when user stops dragging
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $('#rateToPost').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ui.value` in the change event handler.

```
$('#ratingSlider').change(function(e, ui) {
    $('#rateToPost').attr('value', ui.value);
});
```