# jQuery Slider UI Value mixed with Inputs for multiplication computation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

First time posting here. I appreciate any help. I plan on being active and giving help at that!

I looked at other posts and didn't find anything exactly relevant.

This was close: [Getting the value from a jQuery UI Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307325/getting-the-value-from-a-jquery-ui-slider)

Anyone have experience working with jQuery Slider UI?

I am able to pass the initial value of the slider to the script that I have written, but I want to pass the value every time the slider moves to the variable "a" for the #total field.

Any help?

http://jsbin.com/ebahur/21/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need to do. You seem to be able to get the slider's value fine, so what's the issue with getting it to work with the #total field?

Comment: Sorry - I guess I am having trouble passing it to the other javascript function. I don't know why I can't get it to work. This only works on the initial call: var a = $('#slider').slider('value') / 100;

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear, but are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9sLFy/? I moved the function out of your input change so you can call it both when the inputs change and when the slider moves.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO.....Thank you for deciphering my pathetic attempt at explaining my js dilemma....amazing...I can't tell you how relieved I am. How can I +1 or give you credit here?

Comment: Great. If you feel that my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it and selecting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Shoot - one problem is that that slider takes the last value it moved from. So for example if you move up a rank, down a rank, it will display the moved up rank. For instance your numbers are 5, 10 , 15....you move from 5 to 10, and then 10 to 15. Your value should be 15, but it uses 10 to calculate. I think its the order it calls up the calc function. Almost like it needs delayed.

Comment: Try changing from using the slide event to the change event. Ex: `slide: function(event, ui) {` to `change: function(event, ui) {`. If change doesn't do it, then try the stop event.

Comment: DUDE - change works perfect. I O U. Thanks for being so prompt and amazing. I hope you get paid for this...

Comment: Ahahaha - too bad - shooting your company an email. Super impressive work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9sLFy)**

I moved the function out of your input change so you can call it both when the inputs change and when the slider moves.

**jQuery**

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 35,
    min: 20,
    max: 95,
    step: 5,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
        calc();
    }
});

$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));

$('#total').css('color', 'red');

$('input').change(calc);
function calc() {
    var n = $('#n').val();
    var y = $('#y').val() / 100; /*var a = $('#a').val() / 100;*/
    var a = $('#slider').slider('value') / 100;
    var x = $('#x').val();
    var total = n * y * a * x * 0.35;
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
        $('#total').attr('value', total);
    } else {
        alert('Opps Error! Please only numbers');
    }
}
```

​