# jquery ui slider value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm developing an APP using jquery mobile with phonegap. Have a trouble when trying to retrieve the value of a slider, for some reason I can't take it, i've got something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iValue = 0;
    $("#sliderVer").uislider({
        min : 10,
        max : 100,
        orientation : "vertical",
        step : 1,
        value : iValue
    });
    $("#incomplete_field_correo").hide();
    $("#incomplete_field_secret").hide();
    $("#incorrect_field_correo").hide();
});
```

I've tried with

> $("sliderVer").value;

also

> $("sliderVer").slider( "value" );

and

> $("sliderVer").slider( ui.slider );

But nothing seems to work, any idea?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307325/getting-the-value-from-a-jquery-ui-slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get or set the value option, after initialization:

```
// getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

Comment: @AlejandroUnger What do you mean `.uislider("value");`.. are you not using jqueryui..?