# How to check value of multiple range sliders on click of button and then do something based off of value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have three [Jquery UI sliders](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#default). When the user clicks on the next button I need to get the value of each individual slider and check each of them in an if else statement. For example if the first slider is less than 10 it would do one thing, if the first and second slider are less than 10 it would do something else.

You can see a live example of my code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLdKJv

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="eq">
   <span id="one">88</span>
   <span id="two">77</span>
   <span id="three">55</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width:100%">
   <button>CLICK ME</button>
<div>
```

Here's my JS

```
$(function() {
$( "#eq > span" ).each(function() {
  // read initial values from markup and remove that
  var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    orientation: "horizontal"
  });
  $('button').on('click',function(){
     if(this.value < 10){
     $('body').css('background','red');
         }
       })
     });
  });
```

Here's my CSS

```
#eq > span {
 width:120px;
 float:left; 
 margin:15px;
}
#eq{
 width:100%;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
 left:5%;
}
button{
  position: absolute;
  left:20%;
  margin-top:2%;
}
```

So right now I'm not sure how to 1. get the value of each slider on click & 2. check each value after the on click & perform a certain task based off the value of the slider.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307325/getting-the-value-from-a-jquery-ui-slider

Comment: I looked at that, I still don't understand how to grab the value from the 3 different sliders on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to try:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s73mLyja/)</kbd>

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('#eq>span').each(function(){
        var ndx = $(this).index() +1; //which slider you are on (zero-based, so add 1)
        var val = $(this).slider( "value" );

        if (val < 10) $('body').css({'background':'red'});
    });
});
```

---

Also, you could assign each slider and ID and specifically request its value by ID:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('#rpt').html('');
    var s1 = $("#one").slider( "value" );
    var s2 = $("#two").slider( "value" );
    var s3 = $("#three").slider( "value" );

    if (s1 < 10) {
        $('body').css({'background':'red'});
    }else if (s2 < 10){
        $('body').css({'background':'green'});
    }else if (s3 < 10){
        $('body').css({'background':'blue'});
    }

    $('#rpt').html('s1:['+s1+']   s2:[' +s2+ '   s3:['+s3+']');
});
```

[New jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s73mLyja/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
 $('button').on('click',function(){
        if($("#eq > :nth-child(1)").data('ui-slider').options.value > 10){
             console.log('The first value is higher than 10');
        } else {
             console.log('The first value is lower than 10');
        }
        if($("#eq > :nth-child(2)").data('ui-slider').options.value > 10){
             console.log('The second value is higher than 10');
        } else {
             console.log('The second value is lower than 10');
        }
        if($("#eq > :nth-child(3)").data('ui-slider').options.value > 10){
             console.log('The last value is higher than 10');
        } else {
             console.log('The last value is lower than 10');
        }
});
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could achieve what you are trying.

**Basics**
How to get value of slider

```
$( "#one" ).slider( "value" ); //It will return the value of slider one try doing for rest
```

**Next step** Include `slide` and `change` events for sliders and assign a function which will handle your logic

```
$( "#one, #two, #three" ).slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: 255,
  value: 127,
  slide: functionToHandleLogic,
  change: functionToHandleLogic
});
//  $( "#one" ).slider( "value", 255 ); This can be used to set initial value
//  $( "#two" ).slider( "value", 140 );
//  $( "#three" ).slider( "value", 60 );

});
```

`functionToHandleLogic` will be called whenever there is change or sliding on slider.

Now that you know how to `initialize` slider with events and how to get value of slider with `id` of slider. You could club these two together in `functionToHandleLogic`. Fetch all 3 values of sliders in function and decide what it will do.

You could also `initialize` each slider separately and have its own `onchange` and `onslide` function which will do independent thing.

Above solution is dynamic. `Next` button becomes redundant.

If you want to do it on `next` button click then include the logic of `functionToHandleLogic` in button click event and remove `slide` and `change` event from initialization.

**JSFiddle**https://jsfiddle.net/c0p10cxv/
This includes above mentioned solutions. Try changing sliders and button click. Play around and try including your logic. See how it works for you.